# ubuntu server 9.04 nics not visible only lo loopback under ifconfig

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-9.04

hi i have a problem with a 9.04 server deploy, i have two nics and both are now not visible after the server had been off for a month. the client had turned it off as they were moving and now when we boot up the nics are not seen under an ifconfig command, only the lo is listed.

i will have to check on monday to see wheter a sudo lshw -class network will show the nics as being there from a hardware perspective.

i do know the following:

- working prior to turning it off
- we had inet static for our ifaces file so they were hard coded to the ip's
- restarting the unit did not make a difference
- leds on the nic light up when an ethernet cable is plugged into it and then into a switch

we have not tried doing an ifconfig eth0 or eth1 up command yet, i have to wait for the client to get back onsite so that i can walk him through doing this over the phone.

does anyone have any idea why all of a sudden the nics, they are both intel based gig e ethernet, would just not show up anymore with their respective ip address based on the ifaces file? we did verify that the ifaces file has not changed, so i don't think it is anything with that.

thanks.

Comment: Try reseatting the card?  It could be a physical issue.

Comment: Zoredache, you know we never tried that since i was on the phone trying to help out but yes i will have them reseat them and then update this post.gd

Comment: ok the nics are seated properly and no other issues. with a live 10.04 cd the two nics are seen so there is something on my config that is not showing eth0 and eth1 any more suggestions? thanks

Comment: lshw -class network lists the two nics but says DISABLED

Comment: SOLVED: ifconfig -a showed eth2 eth3 and eth4, it seems something happend to eth0 and eth1, when i did a dhclient on eth3 it came up.

Comment: Ah, you may want to modify `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` if you want to fix the device names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After moving equipment one thing that you should check that your card is properly seated.

> ifconfig -a showed eth2 eth3 and eth4, it seems something happend to eth0 and eth1, when i did a dhclient on eth3 it came up.

On a Debian/Ubuntu system the interface naming is controlled by `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.  Feel free to go in and edit that file so that the correct device is given the names that you want.